# Elastic search wildcard query working by text query not

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query where using a wildcard on the filter returns results but using the actual text in the results to do a query returns 0 hits.

This works

```
{
"query": {
"filtered": {
   "query": { "match_all": { } },

  "filter": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "houses",
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": { "match_all": { } },

          "filter": {
            "wildcard": {
               "houses.name": "????"
            }
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
}
```

If it returns a house named "Eve gardens", this returns nothing.

```
    {
"query": {
"filtered": {
   "query": { "match_all": { } },

  "filter": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "houses",
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": { "match_all": { } },

          "filter": {
            "wildcard": {
               "houses.name": "Eve gardens"
            }
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html):

As per your query `houses.name` seems to be an `analyzed` string  which means `Eve gardens` would be tokenized and stored as `eve` , `gardens` not as `Eve gardens` as a whole. As per documentation

> The wildcard query operates on terms. If you use them to query an analyzed field, they will examine each term in the field, not the field as a whole.

So if you do

```
"wildcard": {"houses.name": "Eve gardens"}
```

this will not work.

Try

```
"wildcard": {"houses.name": "eve*"}
```

It should fetch you the results. Hope this helps..

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thank you!